# Offline Qt Documentation

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to compile QDoc following the steps given here https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_Documentation. I am trying to compile QDoc without building the whole Qt project. I use mingw in windows 10. I run first configure in the main qt directory, then configure in qtbase, then make in qtbase. I am going then in the qtdeclarative directory and try to compile sub-qmldevtools as explained in the tutorial. Unfortunately the target is not recognized and no compiling occurs. Can anyone help ?

Comment: it seems that the tutorial is made for an earlier version of qt and does not apply for qt 5.8. i am trying to compile the entire qtdeclarative and qttools modules such that i can succesfully compile qtdoc.

Comment: it seems that the compilation process creates the submodule targets (in the Makefiles) after make module-qtdeclarative (for example) is called. but i do not understand exactly when and how i can only create the targets and exist the make command.

Comment: it seems make qmake_all creates all the required Makefiles in the project. Why should it be called at the end of compilation process ? The Makefiles are needed before that.

Answer (score 3):

I have finally installed the QtDocs. For Qt 5.8 it worked almost as here: https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_Documentation except for make qmake_all should be called immediately after configure is called in the root directory of the sources. Also i had to compile qtattributionsscanner from qttools for the make html_docs to work.

Alternatively to compiling the documentation one could also use zealdocs, that is one offline help tool for varios software APIs.